# jena programming error while reading from an input file .rdf.......Please guide me

Tags: jena

```
package sample;

import java.io.InputStream;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;

public class ReadRDF extends Object {

    static final String fileName = "foaf-ijd.rdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

        InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(fileName);

        if (in == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("File: " + fileName
                    + " not found");
        }

        model.read(in, "");

        model.write(System.out);

    }
}
```

Errors getting populated

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.slf4j.Logger.isTraceEnabled()Z    at
>   com.hp.hpl.jena.util.LocatorFile.open(LocatorFile.java:118)   at
>   com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager.openNoMapOrNull(FileManager.java:527)
>     at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager.openNoMap(FileManager.java:510)
>     at
>   com.hp.hpl.jena.util.LocationMapper.initFromPath(LocationMapper.java:132)
>     at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.LocationMapper.get(LocationMapper.java:61)
>     at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager.makeGlobal(FileManager.java:116)
>     at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager.get(FileManager.java:82)    at
>   sample.ReadRDF.main(ReadRDF.java:17)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can apper, if you don't add to `CLASSPATH` all jar file from `/lib` dir in Jena ditrib.
Also, if version's `slf4j`, which you use, an d jena's slf4j is differenf,  this error can appear.